# Getting OUT_OF_ENERGY error at the TRON's contract call while not all of provided fee_limit was burned

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, method-call, tron

I am trying to call method of the smart-contract deployed on Tron from program code by calling

> /wallet/triggersmartcontract/

Tron node's API.

This worked just fine on the testnet Shasta, but the attempt of executing this on the mainnet failed with OUT_OF_ENERGY error, while from the provided 10 TRX for burning - only 2,8 TRX was burned actually for obtaining 10000 energy. [proof from Tronscan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuOy8.png)

The balance of the caller have more than 10 TRX and there 0 TRX was sent along with the contract's call.

On Shasta - contracts calls by the same code exceeded 10000 energy and I made on purpose calls from accounts with 0 energy in order to force burning TRXs. Everything worked.

Can somebody explain how this happened and how to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can take a looke to this page mabye usefull.
[document of tron](https://developers.tron.network/docs/faq)

there are something about out of energy